# How to get rid of this Facebook Pixel Warning?

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook-pixel

I've been searching for a week now and didn't find any solution for this warning,
the warning is:

> WARNINGS
>
> " We detected event code but the pixel has not activated for this
>   event, so no information was sent to Facebook. This could be due to an
>   error in the code, but could also occur if the pixel fires on a
>   dynamic event such as a button click.Learn more "

And pixel code is: `fbq('track', 'PageView');`

My code:

```
 !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');    
  fbq('consent', 'revoke');   
  fbq('init', /* PIXEL_ID */);
  fbq('track', 'PageView');   
  fbq('consent', 'grant');
```

Please help me to understand what exactly the problem could be and possible solution for it.

Comment: how do you implement your Facebook Pixel in your HTML?

Comment: i've placed the code in the head tag

Comment: Show your code snippet. We can understand the context better if we can see something concrete. Based on the error message it is very likely that something in your code did not run, or you've placed `fbq('track', 'PageView')` incorrectly.

Comment: Sorry for that.. i've edited the question with the code now

Comment: You can try [Pixel Helper](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/support/pixel-helper) to debug.

Comment: I'm already using it and this warning was shown by pixel helper

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to disable AdBlock (this is what works for me)

With **active** AdBlock:

[image]

With **deactivated** AdBlock:

[image]